# What is the easiest way to automatically keep the fluid surface horizontal and the liquid's volume conserved when the container is rotated?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pstricks

I have a symmetric container (a hollow object of revolution) that is partially filled with liquid. When we rotate the container about any axis perpendicular to our display, the surface of liquid must be parallel to the surface of liquid in a not-rotated container.

> To be more realistic, the volume of liquid must be conserved. <s>In other words, the area of the shaded region must be invariant under this rotation.</s>

I want to make an animation by changing the rotation angle so automatic adjustment is a must.

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\psset
{
    PointName=none,
    PointSymbol=none,
}

\def\containerpath
{%
    \pstGeonode
        (0,4){Top}
        (0,0){Bottom}
        (1,0){BottomRight}
        (3,2){Right}
        (1,3.5){NeckRight}
        (1,4){TopRight}
    \pstOrtSym{Top}{Bottom}{BottomRight,Right,NeckRight,TopRight}[BottomLeft,Left,NeckLeft,TopLeft]
    \pscustom
    {
        \pscurve(BottomRight)(Right)(NeckRight)
        \psline(TopRight)(TopLeft)(NeckLeft)
        \pscurve(Left)(BottomLeft)
        \closepath
    }
}

\def\container
{%
    \psset{unit=0.5cm}
    \begin{pspicture}(-3,0)(3,4)
        \psclip{\containerpath}
            \psframe[linewidth=0,linestyle=none,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=gray](-3,0)(3,2)
        \endpsclip
        \containerpath
    \end{pspicture}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(6,2)
    \rput(1.5,1){\container}
    \rput{45}(5,1){\container}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

What is the easiest way to automatically keep the fluid surface horizontal and the volume of liquid conserved when the container is rotated? The top of the container is open so the angle of rotation must not make the liquid spilled out.

It is free for you to use either PSTricks or TikZ or others!

Comment: Draw a horizontal gray rectangle and clip it to the shape of the container.

Comment: @Karl'sstudents: I would think you would need a function for the shape so that you can compute the vertical height to get the same area.

Comment: Certainly the liquid level wouldn't change in a spherical container, what criteria would the container need to satisfy in order for the height of the liquid to be invariant under rotation?  Is convex and symmetric about the vertical axis enough?

Comment: It it the only one shape? If not, what are the constraints for the shape other that it is symmetric? What is the range of the rotation angle?

Comment: @g.kov: The shape is already given by the node coordinates and the curve function is unknown without seeing the implementation. And the range of angle is from 0 to a critical angle `\alpha` where any angle greater than `\alpha` makes the liquid spilled out.

Comment: @Karl's students: you should indicate in the picture that the top is open then.

Comment: @Scott H.: Does the condition "to be parallel" mean that the height of the liquid has to be invariant under rotation?

Comment: @Scott: I guess it just means, that the surface should be horizontal.

Comment: One way would be, for each position, draw an arbitrary horizontal line (can use the last know position as an initial first guess) above the lowest point, and use a Riemann sum to approximate the area under the horizontal line and increase/decrease the height until it is close enough approximation to the original area.  You can use the `intersections` library (sorry only know `tikz`) to compute the intersections with horizontal lines and the edge of the container.

Comment: Sorry for confusing everyone, I was just thinking out loud.  If the height of the water didn't change as the container were rotated, then what was suggested by JLDiaz would be sufficient and no calculation would be needed.

Comment: You mentioned preservation of "area" as a constraint.  But if the body is a body of revolution, then conservation of area will not be the same as conservation of volume.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes: You are so meticulous. You are correct!

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel: I just need the unknown function of the curve paths. Plus making conditional statements for the rotation angle.

Comment: @Karl'sstudents I see that this question remains unanswered.  Giving it more thought leads me to think the best way to do this is, given the vagaries of the container geometry (as well as the challenges of volume integration for the conic section of an unusual body of revolution), to calculate offline the fluid location as a function of the tilt angle, and then, In LaTeX, use a look-up table to plot the liquid, based on the current value of vessel tilt.

Comment: My thoughts: This is a mathematical question that belongs on [math.sx](http://math.stackexchange.com/), as you actually need to solve for the _volume_ that is filled (and not the _area_). When you do have some mathematical solution for the height of the line, that height could easily be calculated and the _area_ could easily be drawn with PSTricks or PGF. — Or do you actually only need the mathematical expression of the `\pscurve`?

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel: I will change the shape to make us easily obtain its function for doing integration. But not now. I have something to do now.

Comment: To solve this, one needs to know the mathematical formulation of the object surface.  The arc creation using `\pscurve` is probably a cubic spline, but I couldn't be sure.  Incidentally, if you made the `{Right}` point at a height of 1.75, instead of 2, the arc surface of the object would likely be parabolic, rather than cubic (being midway from base to neck).  Given that you also (coincidentally) made the initial fluid height to the widest vase section, then, due to symmetry, that particular special case would satisfy volume conservation by having surface always go through the point (0,1.75).

Comment: My prior comment is suffixed by adding that the special case solution I posit (parabolic side wall, initial fill to widest point) will only remain valid until the tilting angle causes the fluid to begin flowing into the bottle-neck region. At that point, symmetry is lost.

Answer (score 2):

this might answer your question, although I'm afraid that this will not keep the volume conserved, because it will take much more math investigated to calculate the contained water. At least this will do the first job for you - keeping the surface parallel to the non-rotated container:

[Bottle http://www.x-linux.de/stackoverflow/bottle.png](http://www.x-linux.de/stackoverflow/bottle.png)

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks,multido}

\def\Bottle#1{{\pscustom[linewidth=2pt]{%
  \rotate{#1} 
  \psline(-1,3.5)(-1,4)(1,4)(1,3.5)
  \pscurve(3,2)(1,0)\psline(-1,0)
  \pscurve(-3,2)(-1,3.5)}}}

\def\BottleWithWater(#1)#2{%
 \rput[c]{#2}(#1){%
   \rput{*0}(0,0){%
   \psclip{\Bottle{#2}}
     \psframe*[linecolor=gray](-6,-2)(6,2)
   \endpsclip}\rput{*0}(0,0){\Bottle{#2}}}}

\begin{document}

\multido{\iA=-45+5}{19}{%
\begin{pspicture}(-2.5,-0.5)(6,5.5)
  \BottleWithWater(1.5,1){\iA}
\end{pspicture}}

\end{document}
```

Note: Don't know who is the original author, found it on [PSTricks](http://tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi)

Regards,
Nick

Comment: *The pink region will tell the history.*